# No audio with Fake KMS rpi4

Tags: audio, pi-4

I can hear audio on HDMI output with the Legacy video output. If I enable the  G2 GL (Fake KMS) it stops working.

I tried removing pulseaudio, install it again with no luck. I also tried to force HDMI audio output. The point is as soon as I set Legacy video output it works fine.

I tried playing audio with asound, mpv and kodi. All with the same results.

- Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- Kernel: Linux 4.19.97-v7l+
- Hardware  : BCM2835
- Revision  : c03112
- Model         : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2

What else can I try ? Thank you

Comment: AFAIK pulseaudio is not installed by default on Raspbian. Have you tried getting audio working on a fully updated, but further unmodified Raspbian download?

Comment: Thank you @Dirk I only downloaded raspbian minimal, then installed  raspberrypi-ui-mods and mpv. Sound was ok but video slow so I set G2 GL. Then video is ok, audio won't. The system is fully updated.

Comment: I tried downloading raspbian desktop instead raspbian minimal. The results are the same. If I use the Legacy video driver, the video is not fluid, but the audio is ok. When I enable G2 GL ( fake KMS ) the video is perfect but no audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it is working. I just updated all the packages of the system and I can hear audio with GL driver on. My guess it is a fix in some of the rpi-eeprom , firmware or linux image packages.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.